# VTK: why the vtkImageBlend result is different from RadiAnt

Tags: vtk

Let's say I have two image, and the artery (the red arrow) is about the same position:

[image]

Now, I need to show the two image in one figure, and I use the `vtkImageBlend` for this purpose. My code is:

```
import vtk

img1 = vtk.vtkDICOMImageReader()
img1.SetFileName('C:\\Users\\MLoong\\Desktop\\dicom_data\\Chang Cheng\\TOF\\IM_0198')
img1.Update()
print('img1: ', img1.GetOutput().GetSpacing())
print('img1: ', img1.GetOutput().GetExtent())

img2 = vtk.vtkDICOMImageReader()
img2.SetFileName('C:\\Users\\MLoong\\Desktop\\dicom_data\\Chang Cheng\\SNAP\\IM_0502')
img2.Update()
print('img2: ', img2.GetOutput().GetSpacing())
print('img2: ', img2.GetOutput().GetExtent())

image_blender = vtk.vtkImageBlend()
image_blender.AddInputConnection(img1.GetOutputPort())
image_blender.AddInputConnection(img2.GetOutputPort())
image_blender.SetOpacity(0, 0.1)
image_blender.SetOpacity(1, 0.9)
image_blender.Update()

imageActor = vtk.vtkImageActor()
windowLevel = vtk.vtkImageMapToWindowLevelColors()
imageActor.GetMapper().SetInputConnection(windowLevel.GetOutputPort())


ren = vtk.vtkRenderer()
ren.AddActor(imageActor)
ren.SetBackground(0.1, 0.2, 0.4)

renWin = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
renWin.AddRenderer(ren)
renWin.SetSize(400, 400)

iren = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
iren.SetRenderWindow(renWin)

windowLevel.SetInputData(image_blender.GetOutput())
windowLevel.Update()

renWin.Render()

iren.Start()
```

And the result is:

[image]

In the above figure, the `img2` is about half ot the `img1`.

Hoever, the printed information is:

```
img1:  (0.3571428656578064, 0.3571428656578064, 1.399999976158142)
img1:  (0, 559, 0, 559, 0, 0)
img2:  (0.5, 0.5, 1.0)
img2:  (0, 319, 0, 319, 0, 0)
```

For `img1`, the extent is (560, 560), and the spacing is (0.357, 0.357). Thus, the `FOV` is: 0.357*560=200, and the `FOV` of `img2` is 160. Thus, I think the blend figure may be wrong.

Moreover, the RadiAnt also provide the fusion figure:

[image]

In the RadiAnt fusion figure, the artery of two images is overlay, which is what I want.

Is there anything wrong with my `vtkImageBlend` code?

Answer (score 0):

From the Detailed Description of vtkImageBlend:

*"blend images together using alpha or opacity
vtkImageBlend takes L, LA, RGB, or RGBA images as input and blends them according to the alpha values and/or the opacity setting for each input.*

*The spacing, origin, extent, and number of components of the output are the same as those for the first input."*

So, you need to make sure to have the same spacing, extent and origin.

The way to solve it is to create new 2 vtkImageData with the same properties and copy your existing data to the new images.
Here I handle extent:

```
private static void AdjustImage(ref vtkImageData oldImage, int[] newDimensions)
{
    vtkImageData newImage = new vtkImageData();
    vtkInformation info = new vtkInformation();
    int[] oldDimensions = oldImage.GetDimensions();
    double[] spacing = oldImage.GetSpacing();

    newImage.SetDimensions(newDimensions[0], newDimensions[1], newDimensions[2]);
    vtkImageData.SetScalarType(4/*VTK_SHORT*/, info);
    vtkImageData.SetNumberOfScalarComponents(1, info);//The components that each pixel needs to represent =1 is the index quantity map      
    newImage.AllocateScalars(info);//It is very important to allocate memory and generate image data. After the image is generated, the default value of all pixels is 0 
    newImage.SetSpacing(spacing[0], spacing[1], spacing[2]);

    vtkImageData data = oldImage;
        Parallel.For(0, newDimensions[0], i =>
        {
            if (i < oldDimensions[0])
            {
                Parallel.For(0, newDimensions[1], j =>
                {
                    if (j < oldDimensions[1])
                    {
                        Parallel.For(0, newDimensions[2], k =>
                        {
                            if (k < oldDimensions[2])
                            {
                                newImage.SetScalarComponentFromDouble(i, j,
                                    newDimensions[2] - 1 - k, 0,
                                    data.GetScalarComponentAsDouble(i, j,
                                        oldDimensions[2] - 1 - k, 0));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                SetImageToDefault(newImage, newDimensions, i, j, k);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        SetImageToDefault(newImage, newDimensions, i, j);
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                SetImageToDefault(newImage, newDimensions, i);
            }
        });

        oldImage.Dispose();
        oldImage = newImage;
}

private static void SetImageToDefault(vtkImageData img, int[] imageDimensions, int i, int j, int k)
{
    const double transparentHu = -1000;
    img.SetScalarComponentFromDouble(i, j, imageDimensions[2] - 1 - k, 0, transparentHu);
}
```

Afterward you will need to translate the second image by the delta of the differences between the 2 images origins.